# Can't get Temperature table to work in java

Tags: java

I've been trying to get this program to work for hours now.  I managed to get the Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion to work, but for the life of me I can't do the same for the Celsius to Fahrenheit.  I'm going to ask my teacher when school starts up again, but as of now I would appreciate some help.  Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //variables
            double number;
            int maxFahrenheit = 52;
            int maxCelsius = 20;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            //user input
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 to convert from Fahrenheit to" +
                " Celsius");
            System.out.println("Please enter 2 to convert from Celsius to" +
                " Fahrenheit");
            number = keyboard.nextDouble();

            //if else 
            if (number == 1) {
                System.out.println("Celsius\t\tFahrenheit");
                System.out.println("---------------------------");

                int i;
                double c;

                for (i = 0, c = 0; i <= maxCelsius; i++, c++) {
                    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + 9 * (i + 32) / 5);
                } //end for
            } //end if
            else if (number == 2) {
                System.out.println("Fahrenheit\t\tCelsius");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

                int i;
                double f;

                for (i = 32, f = 32; i <= maxFahrenheit; i++, f++) {
                    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + 5 * (f - 32) / 9);
                } //end for
            } //end else if
            else {
                System.out.println("Entry is invalid");
            } //end else

        } //end main
} //end TempConvert
```

Comment: You should check your compiler warnings. The value of the local variable c is not used.

Comment: The formula to convert degree Celsius to Farenheit is `1.8*t_c + 32`. `9/5 =1.8` but `9*32/5 = 57,6` . So you are using `1.8*t_c + 57.6` which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a       DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

Look i changed your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variables
    double number;
    int maxFahrenheit = 52;
    int maxCelsius = 20;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //user input
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 to convert from Fahrenheit to" +
    " Celsius");
    System.out.println("Please enter 2 to convert from Celsius to" +
    " Fahrenheit");
    number = keyboard.nextDouble();

    //if else 
    if(number == 1) {
    System.out.println("Celsius\t\tFahrenheit");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");

    int i;
    double c;

    for(i = 0, c = 0; i <= maxCelsius; i++, c++) {
    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" +  9 * (i + 32) / 5);
    }//end for
    }//end if

    else if(number ==2) {
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit\t\tCelsius");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

    int i;
    double f;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    for(i = 32, f = 32; i <= maxFahrenheit; i++, f++) {

    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + df.format(5 * (f - 32) / 9));
    }//end for
    }//end else if

    else {
    System.out.println("Entry is invalid");
    }//end else

    }//end main
    }//end TempConvert
```

Look it works better like google and if you post this in google you will see 42 fahrenheit to celsius

42 = 5.55556

just as your tool =)

Comment: Thx for the quick reply.  The only thing is, we haven't learned  about that stuff in class yet.  I thought maybe i was just doing something silly wrong and it would be easy to point out.  All I really know are loops and if statments right now.

Comment: It is ok pal =) you're learning so you should not know this and yeah there are a lot of changes we could make to this program to make it better, but keep it going =) the world is yours and keep reading a lot =) anything i can help i'd do it for sure ;) if this solved your answerd coud you give me some points? please

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer though.  I tried what you said and is against syntax.  There must be a different solution to the problem that fits more in lines with what we are learning in class :/

Comment: i see yeah i wanna share this with you: There are manny solutions in programming, the point is what is better and why =D,

Comment: Yea for some reason my code right now is just adding 0.032, instead of 32 to each of the values in the loop.  Its driving me a bit crazy.  Is there any reason for this???